# Two Router issue, cannot reach internet

Tags: networking, router, home-networking

I have on ADSL router and one CISCO Wifi Router. The ADSL Router is working fine on its own. I am connecting the lan port of the ADSL Router to the internet(RJ45) port of my Cisco wifi router. But I cannot access the internet from the Cisco router, neither through wifi nor through ethernet connection.

The IP of ADSL router is 192.168.1.1 and the ip of my Wifi router is 192.168.1.100. Should I connect to the LAN port of my Wifi router rather than using the ethernet port(Marked as Internet)?

Comment: I believe you should. Prolly need to turn off the dhcp on the wifi router too.

Comment: That should be when I connect to the LAN port, but my wifi router has port ,specific for internet(Ethernet wire) input, I really dont think this is necessary. I am ready to give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the Wifi router should be plugged into the LAN port of the ADSL router using a LAN port on the wifi router.  The "internet" port of the wifi router should not be used.

While it seems intuitive to plug the "internet" into the wifi router, the wifi router is really just extending your LAN over wifi, so they actually form part of the same network.

You will not be using any of the routing capability of the wifi router, you are just using it to extend the LAN.

You would use the `internet` port only if you were using the wifi router to connect directly to the internet via a modem (which is a different thing to an ADSL router).

Comment: Well my adsl router is a modem?  And it is connected to internet so I guess this is the right setup?

Comment: It sounds like what you're trying to do is set up the Cisco router as an "access point".  If there's a function called that in the Cisco firmware, try that.  Basically, as others have mentioned, it just disables the DHCP server and keeps all routing to within one network.  Which means you want to connect via the LAN ports and not WAN.

Comment: @DeBuGGeR I have hopefully clarified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

2 Routers at the edge of your network means your connections are NAT'd twice - ie, double NAT. Sometimes this configuration works, most of the time it doesn't and causes all kinds of strange routing issues.

Enable the bridging functions on your Cisco device or purchase a stand alone modem.