# Setting up two routers

Tags: networking, router

I have two routers, one of them was provided by my ISP, and I have another one that I flashed with DD-WRT. The ISP router has wireless capabilities, but I'd like to shut it down and use my flashed router as the wireless access point. The ISP router will only serve as a way for my flashed router to access the internet.

The trouble is, I don't know how to configure my flashed router to allow internet access for connected hosts. At first I tried plugging a cable from one of the LAN ports on the ISP router to the internet port from the flashed router. Then, following [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/511623/two-router-issue-cannot-reach-internet), I tried plugging it into one of the LAN ports in the flashed router, instead of the internet port. But still my computer connected to the flashed router didn't have access to the internet.

How should I connect the routers, and which values should I set for the flashed router configurations?

EDIT: My ISP router is a D-LINK DSL-2730B and my flashed router is a Linksys WRT54G V8

Comment: I think you can plug one of the LAN ports on ISP router to one of the LAN ports on your router, that way they'll be in one network (just remember to use single LAN subnet on both routers (ex. 192.168.1.0/24). If you want to disable WLAN on ISP router, go ahead and then turn it on on your router. You should still leave DHCP on ISP router and use it as a default gateway. I don't think it's too good of a scheme but I think it'll work:)

Answer (score 0):

As little info is provided by you in terms of what specific routers you are using, i can only generalize the answer. There are two approaches to this:

1) ISP router has to be set to bridge mode. If you then connect your DD-WRT via its uplink port, the ISP router will just forward everything to your DD-WRT instead. Witch your DD-WRT set to DHCP, it will pick up most of the ISP routers function. Based on what I understood from your question, this is most likely what you want. It also has the advantage of little/no need to make any cotfiguration changes it your ISP router later on if you want to set up things such as port forwarding - It's all handled by your DD-WRT now, where you make the changes

2) Set the ISP router and your DHCP to operate on the same subnet (either static, or rely on DHCP) without any bridging. Your ISP router will then retain most of the settings applied, such as firewalling and port forwarding, and your DD-WRT will mostly just serve as a slave to the ISP routers previous setup. It has the advantage of moving most of the settings upstream and protecting your DD-WRT from most attacks from the outside. Downside is that you now have two points where things such as port forwarding need to be set up.

After that, I'm sure the DD-WRTs defaults will provide internet access to any WiFi connected DHCP clients connected to it. If this doesn't work, try connecting the DD-WRT via its LAN connection instead of its uplink port. As for disabling WiFi on your ISP router, this depends on the type of router in use.

Comment: I edited my question with the router models. I'd like to minimize the configuration changes I'd have to do in the ISP router, so I think I'll go with #2. To set up like that, how should I link both routers? LAN port to LAN port? What should the values of local ip, subnet mask, gateway and local dns be for the Linksys router in this case? WAN configuration values can be whatever, since I'll not be using the internet port, is that right?